# getInputProps in Downshift

Tags: reactjs, downshift

When I render the input element when using Downshift, is it wrong to do

```
<input {...getInputProps({...this.props})} />
```

or should I be more specific in which attributes are passed in the object to getInputProps?

```
{...getInputProps({placeholder: this.props.placeholder})}
```

The later would not then let me add other attributes (e.g. `data-testid:controlName`) without changing my source control to specifically look for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/paypal/downshift), you should pass all props as an object for the input element.  I have not personally used downshift, but I would imagine this would work (and it's always good practice to only pass what you need without additional "clutter"):

```
<input {...getInputProps({
    placeholder: this.props.placeholder,
    data-testid: controlName,
    moreProps: this.props.additionalInfo
})} />
```

However, to be more direct towards your original question, as long as your properties in `this.props` are tagged appropriately (i.e. `placeholder: placeholderValue`) there shouldn't be any problem with spreading `this.props` as the paramater for `getInputProps()`.